# Передача данных между PHP файлами

Tags: php

Есть тестовый сайт на котором форма регистрации находиться в одном файле,а обрабатываеться в другом,обработка устроенна так,что если логин/пароль верны,происходит редирект на форму и создается кука,если же логин/пароль не верны,то просто редирект на форму,но хотелось бы чтоб выше формы выводилась ошибка,которая присваевается некой переменной,а затем та переменная должна попасть в форму,как такое реализовать?
Код формы:

```html
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <h4 style="color: red;"><?=ВОТ СЮДА БУДУ ВСТАВЛЯТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ?></h4><br>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control" value="<?=$_POST['username']?>"><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control"><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="do_auth" value="Log in">
</form>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
  require_once 'includes/config.php';

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);

  if(isset($_POST['do_auth'])) {
    $signin = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "' AND `password` = '". $password."'");

    if( mysqli_num_rows($signin) == 0 ) {
        $login_error = 'Incorrect username or password'; //<<<--- Вот эту переменную нужно передать
        header('Location: admin.php');
        die();
    }

    setcookie('user', $username, time() + 60, "/");
    header('Location: admin.php');

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается с помощью механизма сессий:

```
// Запуск сессии
session_start();

require_once 'includes/config.php';

// Если $_SESSION['error'] не пустой
if (! empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
    // сохранить текст ошибки в переменную
    $login_error = $_SESSION['error'];
    // и очистить сессию, чтоб после обновления
    // страницы текст ошибки не отображался
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
} else {
    $login_error = null;
}

$username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';

if (isset($_POST['do_auth'])) {
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $signin = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "' AND `password` = '". $password."'");

    // Если произошла ошибка
    if( mysqli_num_rows($signin) == 0 ) {
        // сохранить её текст в сессии
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect username or password';
        header('Location: admin.php');
        die;
    }

    setcookie('user', $username, time() + 60, "/");
    header('Location: admin.php');
}

?>

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <h4 style="color: red;"><?= $login_error ?></h4><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control" value="<?= $username ?>"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="do_auth" value="Log in">
</form>
```

---

И ещё - почитайте про "Подготовленные выражения", дабы убрать уязвимость из вашего sql-запроса:

> `"SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '". $password."'"`

Comment: за sql injection шарю,но сделать решил позже,спасибо:)

Comment: @daladn0 в том и проблема, что такие вещи откладывать на потом категорически нельзя